# how to join two database table of joomla and other

Tags: php, join, joomla

I am getting error with this php code.
Can please anyone help me out.

```
$query->select(array('db1', 'db2', 'db3', 'db4', 'db5', 'db6', 'db7'))
  ->from($db->quoteName('table1' , 'a'))
  ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('table2.db1','b'). ' ON(' . $db->quoteName( 'a.db6'). '='. $db->quoteName('b.db6').')')
  ->where($db->quoteName('table1.db3') .'='. $db3)
  ->order('db7 DESC');
```

Thank you.

Comment: omg, this query generators 8-[ but: if  this `'table1' , 'a'` makes an alias `a` for `table1`  then later you have to do `a.db3` not `table1.db3`. I know why i love to write sql-queries by my self :-)

Comment: Is it possible to get the generatetd query, so you can post it here? Or just for debugging for you?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Problem is in ->join() row. Because if i remove this row code work.

Comment: Error: 1064  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'db6=db6 WHERE table1.db3 = 18 ORDER BY db7'

Comment: if I get your example table structure correct the `.db1` in your join is wrong, there should only be `$db->quoteName('table2','b')`. And in the select you may need to prefix the selected columns with the table you want them from (because db1 and db6 exist in your case in table1 and table2)
But your error message does not correspond to your above query, in this case `echo $query; exit` will solve this really quickly, yes it is not fancy but you get the error straight away

Comment: Try `$query->dump()` to get the query also try putting a space between ON and the (.